# Unable to connect Pi3 built in wi-fi to any network

Tags: pi-3, wireless

My Pi3 won't connect to the house network via the inbuilt wireless interface. I've checked all the mods to /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf that are needed as part of the Raspbian Jesse set up, and they match what is required. It seems unable to associate with the SSID and pick up a DHCP lease.

My network/interfaces file:

> auto lo wlan0
>
> > iface lo inet loopback
> >
> > > allow-hotplug wlan0
> > >
> > > iface wlan0 inet dhcp
> > >
> > > > wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

When I run `iwlist wlan0 scan` I am able to see the network to which I want to connect, but when I run `sudo ifup wlan0` I'm told it doesn't receive any lease offers.

I've checked and only a single wpa_supplicant process is running. I've also disabled bluetooth at start up to check try and make sure there are no issues there.

I'm at a bit of a loss as I've no idea what to do next. Anyone able to help?

---

I went back and applied the file as you had provided @Milliways.

It didn't work on either my home network or my mobile phone hotspot. I modified the following line:

`iface wlan0 inet manual` to `iface wlan0 inet dhcp` and it works with the phone but not with the router at home.

There is no "MAC address white list" on the home router, so it's not clear to me why it is unable to connect. Checking the WPA-PSK value, it is correct (and I generated the key the same way for both phone and router).

I am doing it all CLI via a term connection as the pi is headless, so I'm not overly concerned about GUI access.

Comment: Have you fiddled around with /etc/network/interfaces ?

Answer (score 1):

WHY did you fiddle with the configuration files which came with your OS? They should work out of the box. NOTE What you have listed is not correct for any setup.

See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) for correct contents, and how to configure WiFi.

Comment: I went back and applied the file as you had provided @Milliways. It didn't work on either my home network or my mobile phone hotspot. I modified the following line:

`iface wlan0 inet manual`

to 

`iface wlan0 inet dhcp` 

and it works with the phone but not with the router at home. There is no "MAC address white list" on the home router, so it's not clear to me why it is unable to connect. Checking the WPA-PSK value, it is correct (and I generated the key the same way for both phone and router). 

Is there anything else I should check? Could WPA2 be the issue?

Comment: Do not put additional information in Comments, edit into your question. You should also indicate how you tried to setup the WiFi. `iface wlan0 inet dhcp` will prevent `dhcpcd` from working, and prevent the GUI setup from working.